# Parameterization of a path to the summit of $z=1-x^2 -y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, parametrization

I'm trying to parameterize a path to the summit and a path along the level surface $x^2+y^2=1$.
Let's say i start from the point $A=(-1,0,0)$ and i want to end up at the point $B=(1,0,0)$ by taking the two different paths.

If i let $f(x,y,z)=1-x^2 -y^2-z$ and take the direction vector to be the gradient of $f$ at A $\vec\nabla{f}(-1,0,0)$ and by taking the path $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{AB}+t\cdot\vec\nabla{f}(-1,0,0)$,will this get me the desired path that goes through the summit?

For the path along the level surface I was thinking of doing the same thing but taking a direction vector that is perpendicular to the vector $\vec\nabla{f}(-1,0,0)$.Is this also correct?

Comment: $\vec r(0)=(0,0,0)$, which isn’t even on the surface. Moreover, $\nabla f$ is everywhere normal to the surface, so even if you had started at a point on it, this path would leave the surface immediately. As for the second path, there’s an infinite number of vectors perpendicular to $\nabla f$. Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: Ah i see could you give me an advice for constructing the first path?.And for the perpendicular vector i thought i would take $\vec{v}=(-2,0,1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing the parameterization

$$
x = r \cos t\\
y = r \sin t
$$

over the level surface $x^2+y^2 = 1$ you should use $r = 1$ and $ 0 \le t \le \pi$ etc

To the summit taking $t = t_0$ and making $r \rightarrow 0$

[image]

Comment: Thank you i understand the path over the circle ,but i don't understand the path that runs through the summit,could you clear it up please ?

Comment: It is the path described by $(\cos(t_0)r,\sin(t_0)r,1-r^2)$ for $0 \le r \le r_0$. In the plot were used $t_0 = \pi/4$ and $r_0 = 3$

Comment: Ah thank you but one last thing i'm not sure of ,the $1-r^2$ for $z$.Can you please explain to me how you decided that ?

Comment: $z = 1-(x^2+y^2) = 1-(r^2\cos^2 t+r^2\sin^2 t) = 1-r^2$